# How to add tooltip text on my Gridview column header, WPF VS2010

Tags: wpf, gridview, columnheader

Here is my grid i what to give an explanation to the header "RED.BROJ" when on mouse over that header to show the expl. text.

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="50"
                        Header="Реd.Број"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RedenBroj}">
        </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RedenBroj}">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Ред.Број"
                   ToolTip="Your explanation" />                      
    </GridViewColumn.Header>        
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 11):

Slightly late response but you can add a tooltip, without losing the ability to drag columns to reorder them, by doing the following:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50"
                Header="Реd.Број"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RedenBroj}">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="Tool tip content"/>
        </Style>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Update: more concise version thanks to [LPL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620360/lpl)

Further update:  I wanted to be able to have all columns have tooltips that match their headers (as some columns were too narrow to show the whole header):

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}" Header="A"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B}" Header="B"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding C}" Header="C"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I think it could be a little bit less verbose (`<GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle><Style><Setter Property="Control.ToolTip" Value="Tool tip content" /></Style></GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>`) but better solution than mine. +1

Comment: How could I use another value from the GridViewColumn to display a different ToolTip than the content already visible in the header? I tried it with the "Tag" property but although I could use "Tag" as binding in the setter value, I can't assign a "Tag" property to the GridViewColumn like this: <GridViewColumn Header="A" Tag="ToolTip-Content" />

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like answering an old question with your own...

I was inspired by **@Scroog1's** answer but seems a bit redundant having a `Tooltip` which just mimics the content that is there. You usually want the `Tooltip` because you've abbreviated the column header text.

I created a small `AttachedProperty` which I set my `Tooltip` value on the `GridViewColumn`. I then `bind` to this from my `Style` for my `GridViewColumnHeader`.

Now I just define the `Style` once, and add it and the `AttachedProperty` where I want to use it.

#### Xaml

```
    <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Column.(attachedProperties:GridViewColumnHeaderToolTipAttachedProperty.Tooltip), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Style>

    <GridView x:Key="GridViewFuelConsumption"
              x:Shared="False">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Ред.Број"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RedenBroj}"
                        HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}"
                        attachedProperties:GridViewColumnHeaderToolTipAttachedProperty.Tooltip="Your explanation" />
    </GridView>
```

#### AttachedProperty

```
public sealed class GridViewColumnHeaderToolTipAttachedProperty : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Tooltip",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(GridViewColumnHeaderToolTipAttachedProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata("null"));

    public static void SetTooltip(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TooltipSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetTooltip(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(TooltipSourceProperty);
    }
}
```